# Write WKT/WKB to File Geodatabase using FGDB API

Tags: well-known-text, file-geodatabase-api

Is there a way to set the geometry of a row using either WKT or WKB with the File Geodatabase API?

Is there any other way to write spatial data to the file gdb using the fgdb api without having to go through the highly onerous task of defining the number of parts, defining the number of points per part, building point arrays and part collections all before you can finally set the geometry?

Comment: Let OGR do it for you: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the api that ESRI supplies.  There are a few projects out there that have wrapped the fgdb api. https://github.com/geobabbler/FgdbExtensions for example.

Comment: @travis.  The problem w/ this extension is that it does the exact opposite of what I need.  I want to go from wkt -> fgdb.  The extension is for fgdb -> wkt.

Comment: @blah238.  I would love to use that api except I don't know C++ all that well.  I may give the Python version a try.  I'd love it if there was a C# wrapper.

Comment: There is. I haven't used it though: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp